# Pandas timestamp object gives error with strftime()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting, timestamp

I am having data in a csv-file that looks like that:

```
med_intake_time,dose,medicine
09:00,1 pill,aspirin
15:00,2 pills,paracetamol
20:00,1 poll,prozac
```

I can run the following lines without an error message:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file/path/data.csv')
df.med_intake_time = pd.to_datetime(df.med_intake_time)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.med_intake_time.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

and this prints the times as expected. But if I run the following line

```
merged =  ', '.join(f"{row.med_intake_time.strftime("%H:%M")} {row.dose} {row.medicine}" for idx, row in df.iterrows())
```

I get the errormessage `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. If I take away from the problematic line `.strftime("%H:%M")` the code gets executed. I don't understand why once `.strftime("%H:%M")` is executed without a problem and why once it throws an error. Do you know why and do you have a solution? Tnx!

Comment: @DavidErickson No, I have tried this out, but unfortunately it doesn't work either, same error. Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your formatted string:

```
f"{row.med_intake_time.strftime("%H:%M")} {row.dose} {row.medicine}"
```

The quotation marks within the call to `strftime()` are escaping your string, so it's not sure how to handle it. Python is reading it as a series of expressions:

`f"{row.med_intake_time.strftime("` + `%H:%M` + `")} {row.dose} {row.medicine}"`

Try changing the double-quotes within `strftime()` to single-quotes so that they're not closing out the string early:

```
f"{row.med_intake_time.strftime('%H:%M')} {row.dose} {row.medicine}"
```

Comment: Uff, thanks! I totally missed out that the inside double quotes will conflict with the outside double quotes. PS: I appreciate being the first one to accept an answer of yours as correct